# issue when try to push on heroku after cloning it from heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github, git-clone

I cloned a project from heroku which was developed by another developer of my company. I cloned that project from heroku using:
 `heroku git:clone -a "project name"` command. I added some new features to that project and fixed some bugs as well. Everything is working quite well in my local server now. But, now, when I try to push the changes to heroku again using:
`git push heroku master` it is showing the following error :

**Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

Well, when I try to add it remotely using : **git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:{project_name}.git** then it shows: **fatal: remote heroku already exists.**

What is the exact problem? Could anyone please help? Thanks in advance for any kind of help and clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 heroku keys:add
```

I had to run this command. Then everything worked perfectly as expected !